# JAVA WEB (Download MP3 File from URL on Client SIde)

Tags: java

How can i download a MP3 file from URL on Client Side in JSP.

URL should be anything.

sample URL : "http://bollywood.us/songs/Audio/indian/movies/One Night Stand (2016)/01 - Do Peg Maar - Neha Kakkar.mp3"

How can i download this file on Client Side???

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this doesn't *quite* appear to be about programming.

Comment: I am using that code for Download file on Java
but it is not working on JSP Pages.

So Kindly help me...

String sURL=sourceURL.replace(" ", "%20");
URLConnection conn = null; 
conn = new URL(sURL).openConnection();
File outputFile=new File(dURL);
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
OutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int len;
while ((len = is.read(buffer)) > 0) 
{
    outstream.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
outstream.close();
is.close();